# How can I generate self-signed certificate with these standards?

Tags: security, powershell, ssl, certificate, code-signing

I tried creating a certificate using this command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "WDACSigning" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ -Type Codesigning
```

but it causes boot failures when I deploy signed WDAC policy to my VM.
I don't want to setup Windows Server or buy an actual certificate as I'm just trying to test this process.

how can I generate a self-signed certificate that meets these criteria and how to then properly export it to be compliant with these rules?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/use-signed-policies-to-protect-windows-defender-application-control-against-tampering

[image]

Comment: `-KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA` takes care of two of them. Not sure on your policies or encoding cert fields with the encodetypes indicated.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks. it's not about my policies. I simply want to understand how to generate a self signed certificate with the rules Microsoft stated on their official website.

Comment: You misunderstand. I'm referring to the "policies" mentioned in the first bullet point (that they must be signed in PKCS7). Policies are added to Certificates in Powershell using the `-TextExtension` option, described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-textextension

Comment: @FrankThomas I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/about-string-types . does it mean that I just need to adhere to the rules of each encoding? e.g. in the case of PRINTABLE_STRING, I just need to make sure the subject common name or issuer common name include only A-Z
a-z
0-9
' ( ) + , - . / : = ? [space] ?

Comment: well, its saying that a printablestring can contain only those characters, but it isn't saying a string made of only those characters is a printablestring. you can use all those characters in a utf-8 string (or an ASCII string, or whatever else). encodings cover how bytes become characters, so generally if you want to control what bytes a given character/string is composed of, you encode it with a specific type of encoder. I believe powershell uses UTF-8 by default.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @FrankThomas I found a program that looks like it has options to let me create such certificate, could you please check it out and possibly let me know if i can use it to create a compliant certificate for WDAC signing? If you do, you can post it as answer, and i will accept it, i can also update my question to include the software in it. will help other people looking for this solution too, thanks in advance. the software: https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html

Comment: I'd give it a try. I looked at it, and it does seem like it may work, but it doesn't seem to support PKCS#7, and doesn't allow you to set a specific encoding for fields. I have no idea if you actually need to support policies on your cert, and it likely uses compatible encoding. Another tool to consider is Kleopatra (bundled with Gnu Privacy Guard [GPG]).

Answer (score 2):

Self-signed certificates use `UTF-8`. What you need is `Printable_String`. Certificates created by an Enterprise CA role in Windows Server with code signing certificate template, use those specifications.

**Using Self-signed certificates to sign WDAC binaries and deploying them will result in boot failure** and you will need to turn off Secure boot in UEFI to recover from that state.

Use this guide that explains everything step by step for generating a proper certificate for WDAC signing and deployment.

With this method, you can create a certificate with 20+ years expiry date so for at least 2 decades you won't have to repeat the steps again (which take roughly 30 mins).

---

## Create and Deploy Signed WDAC Windows Defender Policy

### Introduction

- By deploying a **Signed** Windows Defender Application Control policy, a system will be secure and resistant to any form of tampering ([if coupled with Bitlocker and other built-in security features](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security)), in a way that **even the system administrator can't tamper or disable this security policy.**
- The [**only** way for this security feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/disable-windows-defender-application-control-policies#removing-wdac-policies) to be turned off, modified, updated or disabled will be to have access to the certificate and certificate's private keys used to sign it.
- [Refer to Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/windows-defender-application-control-design-guide) or [my other wiki posts](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Introduction) If you want to learn about WDAC itself and how to create a customized WDAC for your own environment.
- Always test and deploy your WDAC policy in Audit mode first to make sure it works correctly, before deploying the Signed version of it.

  - The [WDACConfig](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig) module has an optional parameter called `-TestMode` that will deploy the policies with ***Boot Audit on Failure*** and ***Advanced Boot Options Menu*** policy rule options.
- Keep the xml file(s) of the deployed base policy(s) in a safe place, they are needed if you decide to disable the signed deployed WDAC policy later on.

#### Video Guide

### TL;DR (Short version)

1. Install the latest Windows Server, Install AD/DS and AD/CS roles on it. (≈15 mins depending on hardware and if downloaded ISO or VHDX)
2. Use the Enterprise CA's code signing template to create a customized certificate template for WDAC Signing (≈5 minutes)
3. Generate the certificate and use it to sign the WDAC Policy (≈3 minutes)

That's essentially everything we have to do. So, if you are already familiar with the concepts, you can go straight to the bottom of this page and use the resources section to refer to Microsoft guides to create and deploy the Signed WDAC policy.

But if you aren't familiar, keep reading as I've thoroughly explained every step to set up Windows Server, generate signing certificate and sign the WDAC policy. It takes about 20 minutes for me (as you can see in the video) and depending on the hardware, it can even take less time.

---

### Prerequisites

Latest Windows Server, it's free for 180 days for evaluation and comes in ISO and VHDX formats. Preferably use Windows Server insider vNext because it has the newest features and visual upgrades.

- [Download Windows Server 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2022) from [Microsoft Evaluation Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter)
- [Download Windows Server insider vNext](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewserver)

  - [Insider activation keys](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-insiders/bd-p/WindowsServerInsiders)

Once we have our Windows installation media (ISO or VHDX), we need to set up a Hyper-V VM on our host. For this guide, our host is a Windows 11 pro for workstations machine.

Create a Hyper-V VM with these specifications:

- Secure Boot
- Trusted Platform Module (TPM)
- At least 4 virtual processors
- At least 4 GB RAM
- At least ~20 GB storage
- Connect the Default Switch to the VM or create a Private Virtual switch in Virtual Switch Manager of Hyper-V manager, then add it as network adapter hardware to the VM.

### Windows Server VM setup

After Windows Server installation has finished, you can create a [Hyper-V standard checkpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints) so you'll be able to restore the VM's state to this point in time if you misconfigure something later on.

#### Rename the server

Choose a meaningful name, like `CAServer`. Use this [PowerShell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer) to easily do that, it will restart the server to apply the new name.

```
Rename-Computer CAServer -Restart
```

#### Using GUI: Install Active Directory Domain Services

From Server Manager => Add Roles and Features => Role-based or feature-based installation => Select the current server you are on => Select Active Directory Domain Services from the list => Select "Add Features" => Continue the rest of the steps by selecting Next.

After installation is over, open the notifications in the Server Manager, (there will probably be a yellow icon on it), Select "Promote this server to a domain controller".

In the Deployment Configuration window that will be opened, select "Add a new forest" and in the Root domain name, enter a domain name.

It can be anything, even `Bing.com`, but for our usage let's use `CAServer.com`. On the next step, set a password for DSRM (Directory Services Restore Mode), It needs to have uppercase, lowercase and numbers (e.g., Bing6969), write this password down somewhere, like in Sticky notes app on your host.

Next, choose a NetBIOS domain name, the default one will be OK. Confirm and proceed with the rest of the steps by selecting Next and at the end select Install. Wait for the installation to finish. It will restart the Server once the Installation is finished.

#### Using PowerShell: Install Active Directory Domain Services

Install (AD DS) role

```
Install-windowsfeature -name AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools
```

Install a forest and set a forest password

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Bing6969' -AsPlainText -Force

Install-ADDSForest -DomainName CAServer.com -DomainNetbiosName CASERVER0 -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $password -InstallDNS:$false -Force
```

#### Using GUI: Install Active Directory Certification Service and set up an Enterprise root CA (Certificate Authority)

From Server Manager => Add Roles and Features => Role-based or feature-based installation => Select the current server we are on => Select Active Directory Certification Service => Select Next for the rest of the steps and finally select install.

After installation is over, open the notifications in the Server Manager, (there will probably be a yellow icon on it), Select "Configure Active Directory Certificate Service on the destination server".

On the newly opened configuration window, on credentials section select next, on the Role services section check the box for `Certification Authority` and select next.

Select `Enterprise CA` (because Standalone CA does not support certificate templates that we are going to use) and select Next. On the CA Type section select `Root CA`. On the Private Key section select `Create a new private key`.

On the Cryptography section, for Cryptographic Provider choose `RSA#Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider`, for Key length choose `4096`, for Hash Algorithm choose `SHA512` and select Next. On the CA name section select next. On the Validity Period section set validity period to something like 50 Years. Select next for the rest of the sections and finally select Configure.

#### Using PowerShell: Install Active Directory Certification Services and set up an Enterprise root CA

Install Active Directory Certificate Services

```
Install-WindowsFeature Adcs-Cert-Authority -IncludeAllSubFeature
```

Install a new Enterprise CA

```
Install-AdcsCertificationAuthority -CAType EnterpriseRootCa -CryptoProviderName "RSA#Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" -KeyLength 4096 -HashAlgorithmName SHA512 -ValidityPeriod Years -ValidityPeriodUnits 50 -Force
```

Restart the server because it is required, and Server Manager says it too

```
Restart-Computer
```

Lastly do this so that Certification Authority option will be added to Server Manager => Tools and its GUI will become accessible and visible

```
Add-WindowsFeature Adcs-Cert-Authority -IncludeManagementTools
```

#### Configure the Validity period of the issued certificates on the server

[Microsoft official guide for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/change-certificates-expiration-date)

We Increase the validity period of the certificates issued by the CA to 30 years:

```
certutil -setreg ca\ValidityPeriod "Years" 
certutil -setreg ca\ValidityPeriodUnits "30"
```

*Restart the Server after this step.*

You can verify and confirm the results using these commands:

```
certutil -getreg ca\ValidityPeriod 
certutil -getreg ca\ValidityPeriodUnits
```

### Follow the official guide to create certificate template and generate the signing certificate

Now open Certification Authority, you can do so by searching for it in Windows search or from Server Manager => Tools.
Once you open it, you can follow [the official guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-code-signing-cert-for-windows-defender-application-control) to create the certificate template for WDAC policy signing and then request and create a certificate.

Note that If the Server doesn't have at least 1 network adapter connected to it, then Certificate Templates don't load, That's why our Hyper-V VM Server needs at least one Virtual Network Adapter.

The [guide suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-code-signing-cert-for-windows-defender-application-control) using a client computer to request and create the certificate but since we are going to use the certificate for non-domain-joined computers and don't need to use the Active Directory, we can perform all of the steps on the same Windows Server VM.

These are some optional ***deviations*** from the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-code-signing-cert-for-windows-defender-application-control) that **result in creating a successful and more secure certificate** for our WDAC policy signing:

- On the Compatibility tab, you can select Windows Server 2016 from the Certification Authority list and select Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 from the Certificate recipient list.
- On the General tab, you can set the Validity period to 30 years and Renewal period to 22 years. (The maximum allowed Renewal period for the validity period we chose.)
- On the Cryptography tab, you can set the Provider Category to `Key Storage Provider` [(KSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secgloss/c-gly?redirectedfrom=MSDN#_security_cryptographic_service_provider_gly). Set the Algorithm Name to `RSA`. Set the Minimum key size to `4096`. Set Request hash to `SHA512`.

As the [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-code-signing-cert-for-windows-defender-application-control) suggests, you need to go to security tab to verify account access of the user(s) requesting the certificate, **but since we are requesting and creating our certificate on the same CA server, we don't need to change anything there.**

### Create a Signed WDAC policy

Once we have the certificate in the User Certificates store of either the Windows Server or a client machine, Right-click on it => All tasks => Export. Export the **Private key** and export all the Extended Properties, set a password for the certificate and set Encryption to `AES256-SHA256`. Select a location to export and it will create a `.pfx` file.

You also need to export the certificate **without private key**, in `DER encoded binary X.509` format which will create a `.cer` certificate file. We need this certificate to sign the WDAC policy.

It is important to keep these 2 files, specially `.pfx` that contains the private key, in a safe place, such as [Azure Key Vault Managed HSM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/overview) or [OneDrive Personal Vault](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-your-onedrive-files-in-personal-vault-6540ef37-e9bf-4121-a773-56f98dce78c4), so that if you delete all the VMs you created, you will be able to continue using the same certificate to sign further WDAC policies and supplemental policies, at least for the next 22 years, before it needs a renewal. As you can see, all of that setup must be done just once ***every few decades.***

The [Personal Information Exchange (.pfx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/personal-information-exchange---pfx--files) file has great importance because it contains the Public key and **Private key** of the certificate so anyone who has access to this file [can disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/disable-windows-defender-application-control-policies#removing-wdac-policies) the deployed Signed WDAC policy. It should never be shared with anyone outside your circle of trust. It is a password-protected file by nature.

### Use [WDACConfig module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig) to sign and deploy WDAC policies

WDACConfig module with the `Deploy-SignedWDACConfig` [cmdlet](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Deploy-SignedWDACConfig) can automate the entire process of signing and deploying a signed WDAC policy.

```
Deploy-SignedWDACConfig -CertPath <String> -PolicyPaths <String[]> -CertCN <String>
```

**[Cmdlet Info](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Deploy-SignedWDACConfig)**

You need the `signtool.exe` to sign the `.cip` policy binary files.

- [Download the latest Windows stable SDK **installer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/)
- [Download the latest Windows Insider SDK **ISO**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK)

Run it and only select `Windows SDK Signing Tools for Desktop Apps` to install. After that `signtool.exe` will be placed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin` and the WDACConfig module will automatically detect and use it for signing. You can even copy the executable to another location for later usage on another system where SDK is not installed and then use the optional `-SignToolPath <String>` parameter of WDACConfig module to browse for executable.

- *SignTool is also included in the [Windows ADK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) but the one in SDK is the newest and recommended place to get it.*

### Use [WDACConfig module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Remove-WDACConfig) to remove signed and deployed WDAC policies

```
Remove-WDACConfig [-SignedBase] -PolicyPaths <String[]> -CertCN <String>
```

#### **[Parameter Info](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Remove-WDACConfig#remove-wdacconfig--signedbase)**

After running the command above and restarting the system, you need to run this command and restart for a 2nd time, to finish completely removing the signed base policies from the system.

```
Remove-WDACConfig [-UnsignedOrSupplemental] [-PolicyIDs <String[]>] [-PolicyNames <String[]>]
```

#### **[Parameter Info](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Remove-WDACConfig#remove-wdacconfig--unsignedorsupplemental)**

### System Behavior

#### Activation Process

After the signed WDAC policy binary `.cip` is copied to the `EFI` partition as part of the deployment process, and system is restarted oncee, we can see in System Information that WDAC user-mode is being enforced and when you try to install an application not permitted by the deployed policy, it will be successfully blocked. At this point, since we are using UEFI Secure Boot, the **Anti Tampering** protection of the **Signed WDAC** kicks in and starts protecting WDAC policy against any tampering. We need to reboot the system one more time, [to verify everything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/use-signed-policies-to-protect-windows-defender-application-control-against-tampering#verify-and-deploy-the-signed-policy) and make sure there is no boot failure.

Deploying a Signed WDAC policy without restarting is the same as deploying Unsigned policies, because the Signed policy can be easily removed just like an Unsigned policy. So always make sure you restart at least once after deploying a Signed WDAC policy.

#### If Someone forcefully deletes the deployed WDAC policy file

- Deleting the `.cip` policy file from `C:\Windows\System32\CodeIntegrity\CiPolicies\Active` and then restarting the system multiple times won't have any effect at all on the status of WDAC. It will continue to work, and enforcement status will be shown in System Information. **This is how it protects itself against rogue administrators.**
- Deleting the `.cip` policy file from the `EFI` partition located at `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\CIPolicies\Active` and restarting the device will result in a boot failure. Before system restart, nothing happens and it will remain active. This is another self-protection method of a Signed WDAC policy. To recover from this state, the person will need to disable Secure Boot in the UEFI firmware settings. There are only 3 scenarios at this point:

1. If, as suggested in the [Security Recommendations](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security#security-recommendations), you set a strong password for the UEFI firmware of your hardware, they can't access the firmware. This security measure [alongside the rest of the Windows built-in security features](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security) such as Bitlocker device encryption will provide the **Ultimate protection for a Windows device against any threats and any person, no matter physical, real-life or Internet threats.**
2. If UEFI firmware is not password protected, the person can disable Secure Boot and/or TPM in UEFI firmware settings, they can even flash the entire UEFI firmware memory by physically abusing the device to get past the UEFI password, but since the device is Bitlocker protected, **a total Lock Down will be triggered** and the person will need to provide the 48-digit recovery key of the OS drive in order to even complete the boot process into Windows lock screen. Assuming the person also has access to the Windows PIN, they will also need to provide 48-digit recovery password of any subsequent Bitlocker protected drive(s) in order to access them (if the drive(s) aren't set to be auto-unlocked with OS drive). **This is more than Security-In-Depth.** If UEFI firmware has any unpatched vulnerability, Device Guard feautres will take care of it.
3. Since steps 1 and 2 are impossible to bypass for a rouge person, there will be only one option left. To completely recycle the physical device, get rid of the inaccessible hardware such as SSD and then sell the remaining hardware parts. Either way, **your data remains secure and inaccessible to any unauthorized person(s) at all times.**

#### When we activate Smart App Control

After completely deploying the Signed WDAC policy, if we turn on Smart App Control, which is [a variation of WDAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/example-wdac-base-policies), then it will take control of the Windows Defender Application Control User Mode Policy. After turning off Smart App Control, the signed WDAC policy will automatically take the control. So, after deploying the Signed WDAC policy, Smart App Control can either be turned on or turned off, either way, the signed WDAC policy will not be disabled and will turn on as soon as Smart App Control is turned off.

### Resources

- [Use signed policies to protect Windows Defender Application Control against tampering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/use-signed-policies-to-protect-windows-defender-application-control-against-tampering)
- [Create a code signing cert for Windows Defender Application Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/create-code-signing-cert-for-windows-defender-application-control)
- [Deploying signed policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/deployment/deploy-wdac-policies-with-script#deploying-signed-policies)
- [WDAC Policy Wizard](https://webapp-wdac-wizard.azurewebsites.net/)
- [Generate Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policies Online](https://schneegans.de/windows/wdac-policy-generator/)
- [WDAC policy creation - Australian Government](https://desktop.gov.au/blueprint/abac/wdac-policy-creation.html)
- [Understand Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policy rules and file rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/select-types-of-rules-to-create)
- [Install Active Directory Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/deploy/install-active-directory-domain-services--level-100-)
- [Install-AdcsCertificationAuthority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adcsdeployment/install-adcscertificationauthority)
- [Install the Certification Authority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/install-the-certification-authority)
- [Comparison of Standard, Datacenter, and Datacenter: Azure Edition editions of Windows Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/editions-comparison-windows-server-2022?tabs=full-comparison)
- [Remove Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/disable-windows-defender-application-control-policies)
- [Add-SignerRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configci/add-signerrule)